# I can't access an activity on Strava API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to access data for an individual ride using the Strava API but when I add the ride ID I get an error.  Essentially I'd like to be able to access things like distance and times and see this as the first step but I can't pull back much information on a single ride.  Here is the code and error:

```
from stravalib.client import Client


client = Client(access_token='My token here')


athlete = client.get_athlete() # Get John's full athlete record
print("Hello, {}. I know your email is {}".format(athlete.firstname, athlete.email))
# "Hello, John.  I know your email is john@example.com"

activities = client.get_activities(limit=10)
assert len(list(activities)) == 10

#View activities
for x in activities:
    print (x)

#<Activity id=270828720 name='Evening Ride' resource_state=2>
#<Activity id=270590277 name='Morning Ride' resource_state=2>
#<Activity id=270577804 name='Evening Ride' resource_state=2>
#<Activity id=270137878 name='Morning Ride' resource_state=2>


a = client.get_activity(270137878)


#Traceback (most recent call last):

#  File "<ipython-input-22-a7e56786804d>", line 1, in <module>
#    a = client.get_activity(270137878)

#  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stravalib\client.py", line 423, in get_activity
#    return model.Activity.deserialize(raw, bind_client=self)

#  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stravalib\model.py", line 106, in deserialize
#    o.from_dict(v)

#  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stravalib\model.py", line 41, in from_dict
#    raise AttributeError("Error setting attribute {0} on entity {1}, value: {2!r}".format(k, self, v))

#AttributeError: Error setting attribute photos on entity <Activity id=270137878 name=None resource_state=3>, value: {'primary': None, 'count': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer to this? The issue was a change to the Strava API V3 which added photos, and stravalib hadnt been updated to reflect this -

https://github.com/hozn/stravalib/issues/45

Its been fixed now

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to test and respond.  I ended up just doing a download of rides from the site that let me download the full gpx files.